# Inicio e fim de um mês/ano passado em parâmetro (Oracle)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Preciso que retorne os dados totais mensal de acordo com o parâmetro de MÊS e ANO informado.

Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
WHERE a.dt_mesano_referencia between 
to_date('01/'|| :NR_MES ||'/'|| :NR_ANO ||' 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and
last_day(to_date( :NR_MES ||'/'|| :NR_ANO ||' 23:59:59', 'mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Mas ao executar, obtenho o seguinte retorno de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe uma outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Peguei apenas sua condição de where e coloquei em uma consulta  "from Dual" e rodou sem erros. Os parâmetros estão sendo enviados corretamente? Existe mais condições na consulta?

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo  `dt_mesano_referencia`, executei aqui também deu certo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de ver data e hora de inicio e fim, vamos considerar na pesquisa somente o mês e ano.

Para isso precisamos truncar a data para não trazer a hora, depois alteramos o formado da hora com o `to_char`, para trazer somente o mês e o ano, e depois comparamos com os parâmetros passados:

```
 WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(a.dt_mesano_referencia)
              ,'mm/yyyy') = '&NR_MES' || '/' || '&NR_ANO'
```